# Improving the performance of Jpa image load time

Tags: java, performance, image, jpa

I have an application which has to handle a list of objects (retrieved from the database using JPA) which contain an image serialized.

The issue is that when I get around 50 instances of this object stored on the database, it becomes quite slow to load 50 pictures from the database (~5 seconds), which becomes annoying to the user.

Is there a way to set this column from the database to a lazy initialization? Or should I create a separate object to carry the image, and reference it using an ID?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a layz loading attriubte for properties.

```
 @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 private String myBigString;
```

From the JPA 2.0 Specification

> 11.1.6 Basic Annotation The Basic annotation is the simplest type of mapping to a database column. The Basic annotation can be applied to a
>   persistent property or instance variable of any of the following
>   types: Java primitive types, wrappers of the primitive types,
>   java.lang.String, java.math.BigInteger, java.math.BigDecimal,
>   java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar, java.sql.Date, java.sql.Time,
>   java.sql.Timestamp, byte[], Byte[], char[], Character[], enums, and
>   any other type that implements Serializable.
>
> ...
>
> The FetchType enum defines strategies for fetching data from the
>   database: public enum FetchType { LAZY, EAGER };
>
> ...
>
> The LAZY strategy is a hint to the persistence provider runtime that
>   data should be fetched lazily when it is first accessed. The
>   implementation is permitted to eagerly fetch data for which the LAZY
>   strategy hint has been specified. In particular, lazy fetching might
>   only be available for Basic mappings for which property-based access
>   is used.

---

One other technique would to have a second mapping of the same table, but only with the attributes you need.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but I have already tested the @Basic annotation without success. Also, the option of using a table storing pairs of image - id and refer to that ID, is not doable because we have already setted this application on production, and we would need to modify sql databases, which is not intended right now. May be in the future this will have to be done.

Comment: @Josep Rodríguez López: with the second way I do not mean changing the table structure, I simple sugget to have an second java entity that maps to the same table. So you have two, one with the Image column, and one without.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate at least allows for lazy columns (using the fetch attribute of the `@Basic` annotation), but I don't think it's supported by all the JPA vendors.

Is it really necessary to store the images in database? It's often more efficient to store them in the file system, and just store paths in the database.

Comment: It's necessary. I have tested the JPA @basic annotation, but it seems that with my vendor (eclipselink) it's not working properly, so I Guess it is not covered by this implementation.